# Which produces more work: A brick at 300K in a room that's 200K, or a room that's 300K heating a brick that's 200K?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, work

> Which produces more work: A brick at 300K that heat's up a room that's 200K, or a room that's 300K heating a brick that's 200K? The brick's heat capacitance is constant.

I'm having difficulties finding relevant equations to solve this mathematically.

The one that I thought could work would be:

$$ W=C_\textrm{brick}~\mathrm dT + T~\mathrm dS -P~\mathrm dV $$

Where $P~\mathrm dV = 0 $ since the volume stays constant.

Then we have:

$$ W=C_\textrm{brick}~\mathrm dT + T~\mathrm dS $$

Solving the $C~\mathrm dT$ is simple, but does $T~\mathrm dS$ for the brick or for the environment?

Hints are preferable over solutions.

Comment: I don't see there is any work associated with the two processes though there are heat transfer between the air in the room and the brick. Note that, for gas, $W=PdV$.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like this problem is getting at the issue of Carnot-type efficiencies when you are dealing with reservoirs that are not infinite in size.  So you are doing work as heat is transferred from the hotter to the cooler body, until the two bodies come to the same temperature.  The question is, which way gives you more work?  So start with the expression for maximum efficiency (which is the Carnot cycle result), and treat the brick temperature in that expression as variable.  All you'll need is its heat capacity, you don't need TdS because that's already included in the Carnot result.  So take dQ across, find dW assuming maximum efficiency, then find dT to update the T for the next efficiency calculation, and so on until both T are that of a room (it seems you are to treat the room as an infinite reservoir).   It should end up looking like you are doing an integral over all the dW, which you convert into an integral you can actually do over dT.  It's actually a pretty cute question.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do what @Ken G suggests is to assume there is an engine (or engines) with a working fluid that operates in cycles, so its change in entropy is zero.  Therefore, for maximum work, the net change in entropy of the brick and room combination for each of the two scenarios will have to be zero.  This will enable you to determine the final temperature in each scenario.  You can then determine the amount of heat transferred to or from the brick and room in each scenario.  The net amount of heat transferred will be equal to the maximum amount of work done.